# Are human beings evolved to eat meat?

Tags: human-biology, evolution, zoology, food

I know humans can cook and prepare almost anything, but are humans specifically adapted to eat meat?

One of my doubts humans are not particularly well adapted to eat meat because they lack canine teeth. I read more reasons for this [here](http://www.celestialhealing.net/physicalveg3.htm).

What does an evolutionary biologist have to say on this matter? Perhaps evolutionary biology is the field related to this?

Some links supporting my doubt:

- http://www.peta2.com/blog/humans-supposed-eat-meat/
- http://mindfullybliss.com/humans-are-designed-to-eat-meat/

Comment: Please correct my question edit it for something wrong and put related tags

Comment: Human beings, or any living creatures, are not *designed* to do anything. There is no "design" in evolution, merely the accumulation of changes in gene frequencies.

Comment: And of course humans have canines - just look in a mirror. I'm not likely to trust *anything* published on "celestialhealing.net"...

Comment: what about the lost tail bone that we have, i think i used the design as the wrong word . but if you say the accumulation of changes in gene frequencies what accumulation of changes in gene frequencies so far we have been got up to from thousand of years back to us humans.are we vegetarins or carnivores or both.I know we can cook and eat anything

Comment: have you googled any of that questions?

Comment: yes i did, http://www.rense.com/general20/meant.htm and http://www.celestialhealing.net/physicalveg3.htm

Comment: @MattDMo we have canines but why they are so under developed and not like a tiger

Comment: that is another secondary benifit from large canines i guess but primarily i think it is for ripping out flesh, holding a prey with claws and large  canines, and puttting those canines on the neck of the prey kiiling them perhaps by stopping airflow

Comment: If you really think humans were "designed", you should move this question to your religion-of-choice site.

Comment: @jamesqf design was a wrong word i should have used evolved instead i guess.I think comment from kelt [here](http://mindfullybliss.com/humans-are-designed-to-eat-meat/) is good explanation for this.It seems like an answer that should be here in biology.stackexchange.com for my question.OK, I changed it to evolved

Answer (score 1):

@Munish: I will rebut that page, even if Mr. Blomstrom has begun to do so.

1. Carnivores don't swallow food whole.  That's why they have other teeth rather than just four large fangs.
2. Birds have no teeth.  There are many birds of prey that eat other animals, and there are birds that are nut/seed/fruit eaters.
3. Stomach acid: we have an extremely strong acid in our stomach, that if it weren't for a mucous layer protecting us, we would have a dissolved stomach.  Average pH of stomach acid is about 1 to 3.5 - that's very acidic.
4. Our intestinal tract is intermediate.  Well suited for both, not just one.  More importantly we lack the enzymes that can break down cellulose in plants.  If we were strict herbivores, wouldn't it make sense to have the enzymes necessary?
5. We are probably the best hunters on earth.  We have been able to hunt and kill almost any animal wanted and allowed.  We have highly developed brains that allowed us to invent firearms and send men to the moon.  People around the world rely on fishing for their dinner, and hunt deer legally for food.  Hunting is just not that economical for most people.
6. To say that were weren't designed to process flesh is absurd.  I ate beef the last two evenings.  Safe food handling is the contributing factor in "meat illness", unless the person eating has a GI disorder.
7. http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1262767/ : This is one journal that concluded there was no evident relationship between excess protein intake and renal function.

That is a vegan website, and should stimulate skepticism considering they have a bias.  The point I'm trying to show isn't that we are made to eat meat, but rather choose for yourself.  Gain the information you need and make the choice based on the lifestyle you would enjoy more.

Comment: we can't eat raw meat like other animals do.i don't if our stomach will favour that , it won't taste good either but we can eat raw veggies and it tastes good. though there are some people who eat raw meat on live TV shows it seems favourable to their stomach

Comment: @munish: Humans certainly can eat raw meat, as attested by e.g. innumerable sushi bars.  Likewise, there are a good number of vegetables that can't be eaten unless cooked or otherwise processed, and others, like potatos, that are much better cooked.  There are also far more plants than animals that are actively poisonous when eaten.  It is also quite possible to get food poisoning from improperly-processed plant foods.  Indeed, from news accounts this seems more common than meat-related food poisoning.

Comment: Humans(aghoris) will do anything [even eat discarded dead human bodies raw](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mkbvRyaX8kU).Thats survival to save money, or may be religion

Comment: @jamesqf Great response, well said.  munish there is also a dish called steak tartare which is raw meat.  We can eat raw meat, but with all of the possible pathogens, it is advised to properly cook it first.  Many wild animals who eat raw flesh also can have a higher chance of parasitism, so it does come with negatives.

Comment: @MG_MD you are right that is a vegan website so they are vouching for that,  but i am not sure about [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2uTJsZrX2wI), do you have to say anything or those guys are wrong/manipulative.is this some sort of consipracy theory?the video and arguments seems legitimate.

Comment: @munish: If you want an answer, or even a comment, please post a link to readable text.  I do not wish to waste my time trying to extract information from videos.

Comment: @jamesqf though its not related to my question heres the [link](http://www.cowspiracy.com/facts), just scroll down if you dont want to see the video

Comment: @munish I know that farming animals is not as ideal environmentally as hunting.  The sheer demand and amount of animals raised for consumption is beyond staggering.

Comment: @munish: Thanks for the text link.  However, it seems obvious that they are not addressing whether humans evolved to eat meat (the answer to that seems trivially yes, since basically all human societies do eat meat, when they can get it), but how & whether modern industrial agricultural methods can sustain massive human populations without causing environmental damage.  So one might, with equal justification, ask whether humans evolved to live in large cities, getting their food from supermarkets, instead of hunting & gathering.